# What's the most native way to connect android app to a webserver?

Tags: java, android

I'm new to android developing but I have an app in mind, that needs to be connected to a Webserver (implemented as a java servlet if it makes a difference) in order to receive data (both real-time ajax-like and not real-time). What's the best way to perform such communication in the android interfaces ?

Thanks In Advance,
Chris

Comment: If you need to perform intermittent communication then you should be using Google C2DM: http://code.google.com/android/c2dm/index.html

Answer (score 1):

Just use a [HttpClient](http://developer.android.com/reference/org/apache/http/client/HttpClient.html).